# I'd like to use a dataset and create multiple graphs from it. Does Zepplin support this?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I would like to issue one complex query and create multiple graphs from it.  Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Zeppelin Tutorial](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/quickstart/tutorial.html) and the related sample notebook installed by default.  In the first paragraph, it shows how to build a data set for both API and SQL use.  The same data set is then used in later paragraphs.  From the tutorial notebook in version 0.6.2:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.net.URL
import java.nio.charset.Charset

// Zeppelin creates and injects sc (SparkContext) and sqlContext (HiveContext or SqlContext)
// So you don't need create them manually

// load bank data
val bankText = sc.parallelize(
    IOUtils.toString(
        new URL("https://s3.amazonaws.com/apache-zeppelin/tutorial/bank/bank.csv"),
        Charset.forName("utf8")).split("\n"))

case class Bank(age: Integer, job: String, marital: String, education: String, balance: Integer)

val bank = bankText.map(s => s.split(";")).filter(s => s(0) != "\"age\"").map(
    s => Bank(s(0).toInt, 
            s(1).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(2).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(3).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(5).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt
        )
).toDF()
bank.registerTempTable("bank")
```

You can then reference this using Spark SQL:

```
%sql
select * from bank limit 5
```

Or use the bank DataFrame directly:

```
%spark
bank.show(5)
```